# aurelia: Custom defined VM in your VM

Tags: aurelia

Hi I am looking for a way to probarly add new VM objects in my current VM
Can anyone help me how to do this?

The idea is that this should output

```
Hi!
my name is jhonny
```

Code i have so far

```
import {foo} from 'dist/foo';

export class Main{
  constructor(){
    this.heading = "hi!"
    this.fooVar = new Foo("jhonny");
  }
}

<template>
  <section>
    <h2>${heading}</h2>

    <import from="./foo"></import>
    <foo item.bind="fooVar"></foo>
  </section>
</template>



export class Foo{

  static Behavior(){
    return Behavior
      .customElement('foo');
  }

  constructor(name){
      this.name = name;
  }
}

<template>
  <section>
    <h2>my name is ${name}</h2>
  </section>
</template>
```

Also tried

```
<foo item.bind="fooVar"></foo>
<foo bind="fooVar"></foo>
<foo model.bind="fooVar"></foo>

 <compose
      model.bind="fooVar"
      view-model="foo">
    </compose>
```

They all give "my name is" without the variable name. So i guess its not binding

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to instantiate the Foo.

and it probably should be:

```
<foo name.bind="fooVar"></foo>
```

and

```
Behaviour.withProperty('name');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your stated goal is: Add VM object in current VM.  Here's the code for that (it removes the "custom element" you were adding, and uses instead a property in the main VM that is itself an object):

```
export class Main{
  constructor(){
    this.heading = "hi!"
    this.fooVar = new Foo("jhonny");
  }
}

<template>
  <section>
    <h2>${heading}</h2>
    <h2>my name is ${fooVar.name}</h2>
  </section>
</template>

export class Foo{
  constructor(name){
      this.name = name;
  }
}
```

I created a [sandbox code project](https://github.com/cmichaelgraham/aurelia-typescript/tree/master/code-sandbox) to illustrate the above (it is written in TypeScript)

If you want to try out the sandbox code project, [here are the instructions](https://github.com/cmichaelgraham/aurelia-typescript#code-sandbox---place-to-illustrate-various-code-usage)

I added an [Aurelia TypeScript Wizard Navigation Sample](https://github.com/cmichaelgraham/aurelia-typescript/tree/master/code-sandbox#wizard-routing-sample) to show an alternative to the approach you asked about.